# How come in biuret test the copper sulfate doesn't react with the sodium hydroxide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, solutions, proteins, carbohydrates

As I understand the color change in the biuret test is due to the formation of a complex between the peptide (with more than 2 peptide bonds) and the $\ce{Cu^2+}$ ion, from $\ce{CuSO4}$. But before adding the $\ce{CuSO4}$ we add a base to our solution in this case $\ce{NaOH}$, my book says that's because we want an alkaline environment in order for the reaction to happen.

Shouldn't $\ce{CuSO4}$ react with the $\ce{NaOH}$  and then their product $\ce{Cu(OH)2}$ will precipitate?

Or at least both should happen. Every YouTube video I've seen, of the Biuret test, shows both tubes being clear and only a color change, and no percipitation.

In another case for example a Fehling's test for reducing sugars we add an extra compound (sodium potassium tartrate) in order to prevent $\ce{Cu^2+}$ reacting with the $\ce{OH-}$, why not in the biuret test?

Comment: Don't trust random YouTube videos. Internet is very ueful but it is also full of incorect information. You have to seek *reliable* sources from the internet for example, pages maintained by universities ending in edu in the address. See this one for example, https://www.clear.rice.edu/bioc111/bios111_biuret.htm

Comment: It does add potassium tartarate to avoid problems, which you just mentioned in the question.

Comment: What you need for this test is $\ce{Cu^2+}$ cation. Hope [answer here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/60428/principle-of-the-biuret-test) give you insight.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne I've already reviewed that  question but still got no answer to mine. Why the Cu2+ ions don't react with the NaOH as well?

Comment: @AChem the videos were just the same Biuret test demonstration, i watched them to see if other people had different findings. I was trying to see if percipitation did happen in any of them.

Comment: Fehling's  and Biuret reagents are complex mixtures, formation of which cannot explain by simple reactions. [Here](https://doi.org/10.1002/ejic.201600168) explaing why.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne thank you for taking the time to reply and sharing this paper. It'll take me some time reading and understanding this one, when I figure this out I'm gonna post it here. Thanks once again

Comment: A similar effect is in the formation of a copper-ammonia complex in the cuprammonium reagent used in making  one type of rayon (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuprammonium_rayon). Though it is in a highly alkaline solution, copper doesn't precipitate because it is bound to ammonia.